# Javascript | Botón suma las veces que hemos pulsado el botón. Pero por error sólo suma si refresco la página

Tags: javascript

EL objetivo es que al pulsar el botón "siguiente número", los números vayan aumentando. Pero sólo me muestra las veces que va sumando si refresco la página. Si no refresco la página y le doy al botón no me sigue contando. ¿Qué hago mal?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    function count() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("count") === null) {
        count=0;
        }
        else{
        count= localStorage.getItem('count');
        }
        count++;
        localStorage.setItem('count', count);
        count = localStorage.getItem('count');
        document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = count;
      }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <h1 id="write">0</h1>
  <button id="idButton" onclick='count()'>Siguiente número</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te muestra el valor guardado porque al cargar la página nunca estas pidiendo que lo imprima.

Para solucionarlo podes crear una función, por ejemplo, `getCount` que busque el valor guardado y lo imprima en el element `write`.

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<h1 id="write">0</h1>
<button id="idButton" onclick='count()'>Siguiente número</button>

<script>
  // Función que imprime el contador
  function getCount() {
    let count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 0;
    document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = count;
  }
  
  // Función que incrementa el contador
  function count() {
    let count = localStorage.getItem("count") || 0;
    count++;
    localStorage.setItem('count', count);
    // Llamamos a la función que imprime
    getCount();
  }

  // Llamamos a la función que imprime
  getCount();
</script>
```